# Questions related to definition of product/sum/union/intersection of subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H, K \leq G$. Then, if I am not wrong, we can define the following structures:

$HK = \{hk \space|h \in H, k\in K \}$

$H+K = \{h+k \space|h \in H, k\in K \}$

$H \cup K = \{x \space|x \in H \space or \space x\in K \}$

$H \cap K = \{x \space|x \in H \space and \space x\in K \}$

My first question is, are those definitions correct? What constraints should I add to the definitions? I know that I can not multiply or sum up infinitely many elements. So should I write for example that $HK = \{h_1k_1 +\dots +h_nk_n  \space|h \in H, k\in K \}$?

Comment: Unless $G$ is a ring, you should use only one of multiplication or addition as your operation. Statements like $hk $ and $h+k $ make sense, but $hk +fg $ do not (as there are two operations present in the third).

Comment: If you mean *setwise* (inside a group) then yes: they're right (although $\;H+K\;$ seems to assume you take an additive operation, whereas $\;HK\;$ is multiplicationwise...confusing)...yet you tagged "groups" your question, so do you *really want to ask* about the subgroups generated by those definitions, or *what*?

Comment: @DKS, I consider $G$ as a group. Then how should I give the definitions of $HK$ and $H+K$? Is it the same?

Comment: @DonAntonio, I want to ask about subgroups generated by those definitions. I appreciate that if you could give me the definitons by taking $G$ as a ring.